# Wrap middle div to next line

Tags: html, css

I have three divs that are horizontally aligned.

|--DIV1--||--DIV2--||--DIV3--|

However, when the size of the window shrinks, I want the center div to move to the next line and to fill the whole line.

|--DIV1--||--DIV3--|

|--------DIV2--------|

The widths of the divs are dynamic so their width changes depending on what is loaded on the page, so I cannot use a measured width to change which css style to use. Any ideas on how to go about this?

Comment: a starting point that can help: https://jsfiddle.net/ot1pd904/

Comment: Could you provide as with a concrete example and/or the code you have already tried ?

Comment: Here I created something for you: https://jsfiddle.net/z1o50pvL/

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is wrap your 3 divs in another div that has is set to `display: flex`. You can then set media queries for each of your breakpoints and set the `order` css value accordingly.

```css
.container {
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
flex-direction: row;
}

.container .div1 {
order: 1;
width: 33%;
background-color: blue;
}

.container .div2 {
order: 2;
width: 33%;
background-color: red;
}

.container .div3 {
order: 3;
width: 33%;
background-color: orange;
}

@media all AND (max-width: 900px) {

.container .div1 {
width: 50%;
}

.container .div2 {
order: 3;
width: 100%;
}

.container .div3 {
order: 2;
width: 50%;
}
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="div1">div 1</div>
<div class="div2">div 2</div>
<div class="div3">div 3</div>
</div>
```